# Update npm installed packages - npm ERR! code EINVALIDPACKAGENAME

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to update my node modules globally. I'm using this command

```
sudo npm update -g
```

but it will produce thise error in terminal

```js
npm ERR! code EINVALIDPACKAGENAME
npm ERR! Invalid package name ".DS_Store": name cannot start with a period

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/dev/.npm/_logs/2021-04-24T15_59_25_014Z-debug.log
```

I think that the command will scan the folder and find macOS `.DS_Store` file.

How I can fix this?

Comment: This seems similar to [issue #2835](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2835)

Comment: @RobC I've readed it but I'm unable to find the `.DS_Store` file anywhere. I've also enabled hidden files visualization but nothing :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

for me doing this solve my problem :

```
find /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ -name '.DS_Store' -type f -delete
```

It search all .DS_Store and remove it in the global node_modules folder ( on Mac )

Comment: if you are using fnm as your node version manager and multishells, try this:
`find ${FNM_MULTISHELL_PATH}/lib/node_modules/ -name '.DS_Store' -type f -delete`

Answer (score 14):

I solved the same issue for Mac OS Monterey using this

```
find `npm list -g | head -1` -name '.DS_Store' -type f -delete
```

Comment: This one works also if you use nvm. Thanks for it!

Answer (score 2):

### 1. Solution

**For Windows users**.

Delete the folder with the incorrect name.

I have it at the address:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules
```

According to Laertes Moustakas (at the time of writing my answer, his GitHub comment has 9 likes), [**the folder with the incorrect name may be located at the different address**](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2835):

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
```

### 2. My example

I was getting the error:

```js
D:\SashaDebugging>npm update -g
npm ERR! code EINVALIDPACKAGENAME
npm ERR! Invalid package name ".corepack-yRBjKBW1" of package ".corepack-yRBjKBW1@*": name cannot start with a period.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\SashaChernykh\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-02-04T06_33_17_981Z-debug-0.log
```

I deleted the folder:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\.corepack-yRBjKBW1
```

Now I can successfully update my npm packages:

```js
D:\SashaDebugging>npm update -g

added 180 packages, removed 236 packages, and changed 2338 packages in 36m

369 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
```

### 3. My environment

1. Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.1415]
2. Node.js 19.6.0
3. npm 9.4.1

### 4. Disclaimer

This answer is relevant for February 2023. In the future, its data may be outdated.

This solution may not work on a different environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one,

```sh
sudo npm install --global npm
```

I think this is going to work for you

Answer (score 0):

**For Windows, an alternative**

I was getting the error with the `mime-type;s` package:

```js
npm ERR! code EINVALIDPACKAGENAME
npm ERR! Invalid package name "mime-type;s" of package "mime-type;s@~2.1.34": name can only contain URL-friendly characters.
```

I resolved this by deleting the line with the module name `mime-type;s` inside the project `package-lock.json` file since I could not find `mime-type;s` in either `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules` and  `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\.` directories